# Fill 2D array with numbers in C

Tags: c

sI need to make simple 2D array of defined size and fill it with numbers starting from 1, any ideas? thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int mat[][],  a, b, c, d;

   printf("Number of rows and cumluns?\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
   /* zadam 3 a 4*/
   for (c = 0; c < a; c++)
      for (d = 0; d < b; d++)
         mat[c][d]

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to allocate memory to this 2d array.
For example, you getting the user input with variable "a" and "b"
so you could declare the the array after the user input like this

```
   int a, b, c, d;

   printf("Number of rows and cumluns?\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
   int mat[a][b];
```

After you done allocate the memory you needed for the array, you will need to allocate the value you want in each position ( depends on c & d variables ), for example I used d variable values and assigned them to the 2nd array:

```
for (c = 0; c <= a; c++)
  for (d = 0; d <= b; d++)
     mat[c][d]=d;
```

Then you will probably want to print the array so, same For loops, just with print

```
for (c = 0; c < a; c++){
  for (d = 0; d < b; d++)
     printf("%d ",mat[c][d]);
printf("\n");
```

Output if a = 2 and b = 4

[image]

Also in your original code, you forgot a ";" after the mat[c][d] aswell.

Hopefully this will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a,b,i,j,k=1;
printf("Enter the no of row and col\n");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
int arr[a][b];
for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b;j++){
        arr[i][j]=k;
        k++;
    }
}
for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b;j++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
    }printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

I'll just point out that you haven't allocated any memory for the 2D array. 
Use `malloc` if dynamic, otherwise statically allocate e.g. `int mat[20][20]`

Comment: He wants a ```simple array```. Why are you frightening him with a ```*```? :-)